# How to remove a page from google analytics UI?

Tags: google-analytics

I mistakenly used google analytics code of another website and now, in another site's google analytics report, it shows wrong URLs (because it is of my new website's),

How can I remove those URLs/Pages from google analytics' account.

Example,

I have abc.com website's google analytics code and I mistakenly used it in def.com's website.

There is a URL on def.com/new-year and it shows on abc.com's google analytics on Acquisition => All Traffic => Channels,

Is there any way I can remove the record from google's generated table ?

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

1. Use the time selector and set it to a date after the wrong tracking code was removed.
2. Use the hostname secondary dimension in the report and thus remove all traffic to the wrong hostname.
3. Duplicate the view and then delete it. But you will lose all the data so this is rather drastic.